# jQuery iterate through elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML.

```
<div id="price_list">
 <input type="text" value="100" class="input_price" />
 <input type="text" value="256" class="input_price" />
 <input type="text" value="500" class="input_price" />
 <input type="text" value="04.26" class="input_price" />
 <input type="text" value="156" class="input_price" />
 <input type="text" value="052" class="input_price" />
 <input type="text" value="692" class="input_price" />
 <input type="text" value="25.36" class="input_price" />
 <input type="text" value="10.56" class="input_price" />
</div>
```

What is the best way to get the SUM of values of the elements having class `input_price`?

Please note that I am concerned about the performance. My actual HTML is bit more complex (sometimes I have thousands of elements). I tried using `.each()` but sometimes my browser gets stuck. So that the question can be modified to "What is the best way to iterate through elements TO GET some data?"

My try:

```
var total = 0;

$(".input_price").each(function(){
  total+=parseFloat($(this).val());    
});
```

Comment: You should post, how you are using `each`.

Comment: It could be a good idea to show us the code you tried with .each(), maybe someone can improve it.

Comment: Is this done multiple times in the page

Comment: @ArunPJohny Good Catch, Yes. But in separate events.

Comment: In that case it will be better to cache the result of `$(".input_price")`

Comment: @alexxus - I've rolled back your edit because you changed Red's `parseFloat()` to `parseInt()`. Please don't make changes to code provided in questions - if you think `parseInt()` is more appropriate say so in a comment. (Note also that using `parseInt()` without supplying the radix in the second parameter is a _really_ bad idea when parsing user-entered values.)

Comment: @nnnnnn No.. that was my edit ..Not Alexxus.

Comment: @ArunPJohny The values are getting changed, So i cannot cache the result.

Comment: Red - Wait, what? According to the edit history you added code with `parseFloat()` and then Alexxus changed it to `parseInt()`.

Comment: @nnnnnn Not actually, my first edit was with `parseInt` that was my mistake, then i changed it to `parseFloat`.

Comment: Oh, OK. In that case I owe @Alexxus an apology: sorry about that. (Probably he started making his edit while you were making yours; the edit history doesn't reflect multiple consecutive edits by the same person if made within five minutes.)

Comment: @nnnnnn im really SORRY for making a confusion.

Comment: @nnnnnn Wow, that was weird. I would never change code in questions because it would affect the meaning of it and the answers too. I only changed code formatting for better readability. Nothing else. Nevertheless I accept your apology :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just because you care about performance, use pure JavaScript and a single `for` loop:

```
var list = document.getElementById("price_list"),
    inputs = list.getElementsByTagName("input"),
    total = 0;

for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
    total += +inputs[i].value;
}

console.log(total);
```

Comment: +1 - good thinking, and fast typing, beat me by half a minute.

Comment: @Red That's the best way to go, if you aim to gain the performance.

Comment: @VisioN bee has a shorter way below. Don't you think thats better.

Comment: @optim No. I meaningly haven't used neither `getElementsByClassName`, nor `querySelectorAll`, since these methods are not supported by old browsers.

Comment: @optim All good developers ***should*** worry. Moreover, my method is faster in Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

In jQuery, you could do this straight:

```
var sum = 0;

$('.input_price').each(function(){
  var value = parseFloat(this.value);
  if(!isNaN(value)) sum += value;
});
```

You could also do [asynchronous looping using timers](http://jsfiddle.net/CDvjH/). *It will take longer* but will not freeze the UI thread so you won't get stuck. Here's [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CDvjH/)  where it sums up an array of 1's until 1000, but won't freeze the browser.

```
function loop(object,callback){
  var i = 0;
  var sum = 0;

  var timer = setInterval(function(){

    //get value and add
    var value = parseFloat(object[i].value);
    if(!isNaN(value)) sum += value;

    //if we reach the length, clear the timer and call the callback
    if(++i === object.length){
      clearInterval(timer);
      callback(sum);
    }
  },0);
}

loop($('.input_price'),function(sum){
  console.log(sum);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var sum = 0;

$('.input_price').each(function(){
    sum += parseFloat(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.input_price').each(function(){
    sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: This will fail in complex iterations.

Comment: Why .Can u explain pls.Really i dont know

Comment: In terms of performance on large element sets , the best idea is to use pure javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Summing all elements with classes as input_price,

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("input_price");
var sum = 0;
for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    sum += parseFloat(elements[i].value);
}
```

Comment: `var sum = parseFloat(0);` Eh? Why is that?